# feedback on considerations of sigma algebras

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the exact formulation behind countable unions and countable intersections being in the sigma-algebra.

If I have a set X
with a sigma algebra on X
Where $A_1, A_2, A_3$ is in X and $\sigma(X)$

Then I ought to have
$\sigma(X) = \left\{X,\emptyset, A_1, A_2, A_3, A_1^c,A_2^c,A_3^c, ...\right\} $ After this i become unsure.

How am I supposed to apply the property $ \left ( A_j \right)_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \subset X \Rightarrow \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb{N}}^{} A_j \in \sigma(X) $

My idea has been that only $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$ is in $\sigma(X)$. But I believe my teacher told me that $j$ is a dummy variable making it so any group of indices can be in the index set for the union.

In example I understood that to mean that both $A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3$ is in $\sigma(X)$

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: *Any* (finite or countable) union of elements of $\sigma (X)$ should be an element of $\sigma(X)$. So your interpretation of your teacher's statement seems correct.

Comment: So by any, is meant that I can take j to be the set [1,2,3], but also [2,3] and [1,3] ?

Comment: Correct. It really means that whenever you select some elements of $\sigma(X)$, their union will be in $\sigma(X)$ again - it does not matter which elements you select (your selection does have to be countable at most, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning looks correct. The point is that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under *countable* unions. So, for example, if the members of the $\sigma$-algebra are indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, then for any $K\subseteq \mathbb{N}$,

\begin{equation*}
\bigcup_{i\in K}{A_{i}}\in \sigma(X).
\end{equation*}

So $K$ can be any arbitrary subset of natural numbers, finite or infinite, and the union $\cup_{i\in K}{A_{i}}$ is still a member of the $\sigma$-algebra. In this way, $i$ truly is a dummy variable that can take on any of the values in the countable index set.